# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object Error while Sending activity instance to another activity as putExtra

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a listener say IListener which is declared as

```
interface IListener : Serializable {
     fun onPurchaseUpdated(transactionResponse: TransactionResponse)
}
```

Where TransactionResponse is Parcelable Object. as shown:

```
@Parcelize
data class TransactionResponse(
    var code: Int?,
    var message: String?,
    var status: String?,
    val orderId: String? = null, 
    val txnId: String? = null,
    val amount: Double? = 0.0,
    val timestamp: String? = null,
    val startDate: String? = null,
    val endDate: String? = null,
    val skuId: Long? = 0,
    val currency: String? = null
) : Parcelable {}
```

My main activity implements this listener and overrides the method onPurchaseUpdated(). From my MainActivity, I launch another activity named MainActivity2 as shown below :

```
val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity2::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(LISTNER, iListenerInstance)
    context.startActivity(intent)
```

Where iListenerInstance is obtained in MainActivity as shown below:

```
val iListenerInstance= this as IListener
```

But when I do this application crashes with following error :

```
Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.abc.sampleclientapp.MainActivity)
```

MainActivity code is

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IListener {
private var isAutoConfirmed = false
private var orderId: String? = null

override fun onPurchaseUpdated(transactionResponse: TransactionResponse) {
    Log.i("Abc", "transactionResponse = $transactionResponse")
    orderId = transactionResponse.orderId
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    buy.requestFocus()
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    isAutoConfirmed = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isAutoConfirmed")
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putBoolean("isAutoConfirmed", isAutoConfirmed)
}

fun buttonClicked(v: View?) {
    when (v!!.id) {

        R.id.buy_new -> {
            requestPayNewApi()
            isAutoConfirmed = false
        }
    }
}

private fun requestPayNewApi() {
    var skuId = sku_id.text.toString()
    if (skuId.isEmpty()) {
        skuId = BuildConfig.DEFAULT_SKU
    }
    val iListener = this as IListener
   val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity2::class.java)
   intent.putExtra(LISTNER, iListenerInstance)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}

private fun getUniqueOrderID(): String {
    val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + (1..9)
    return (1..UNIQUE_ID_LENGTH)
        .map { allowedChars.random() }
        .joinToString("").plus(System.currentTimeMillis())
}

companion object {
    private const val UNIQUE_ID_LENGTH =
        17 // It is 27, UNIQUE_ID_LENGTH + 10 digit UNIX timestamp
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like problem is that we can not serialize an activity context. Hence whenever the Activity or its inner classes are referenced/declared inside listener, Exception is thrown.